# Client application's connectivity with server

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am working on a client application with python. GUI is created with `PyQt`.
Basically, the application connects to the server via `ssh` and retrieves information thereby reading files generated by the server software. I am using `paramko` module.

My question is:

Should I open an `ssh` connectivity right when the client application is started and keep until it quits? Or I should create a new `ssh` connectivity whenever a button in client app triggers information retrieval?
How would it affect the performance?
Any suggestion and reference would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should open the **SSH** connection when you need & close the connection after information retrieval. Here are some reasons why:

1) Generally most server has limited number of connections to the `sshd daemon`. Additional connections will be dropped until authentication succeeds or the `LoginGraceTime` expires for a connection. The default is 10. It is called `MaxStartups`. This setting determines the maximum number of unauthenticated SSH connection attempts. In high concurrency environments having too low of a value causes SSH connection errors. That means in case of multiple client running simultaneously can fail.

2) `MaxSessions` determines the maximum number of open shell sessions allowed per network connection.

3) As Sagan Pariyar mentioned above, open `SSH` port increases server load.

4) Open `SSH` port can be a high risk server security issue.

**Read more:**

- [Best practices for SSH configuration](https://support.asperasoft.com/hc/en-us/articles/221494788-Best-practices-for-SSH-configuration)
- [SSH Essentials](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/ssh-essentials-working-with-ssh-servers-clients-and-keys)
- [SSH port forwarding freezes after 10 simultaneous connections](https://serverfault.com/questions/134367/ssh-port-forwarding-freezes-after-10-simultaneous-connections)

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you have ssh to server 1 port is block from both the side, if you have connection when client starts then it will block that port and no one could communicate to server , also you increasing server load just keeping the connection open. 
So, my advice is to start ssh whenever the need is and stop once task is completed.